# read data from a custom collection (struct Array)

Tags: c++, performance, pointers, collections

i am a beginner in `c++` ..so please help me get this right.

trying to read from the collection, in one version of implementation I have tried ,there was some bippings from the console, another test.. displays numbers so its probably the pointer to the string...

the code is as follows

**DataCollection.h**

```
typedef struct _DataC
{
    char* buffer;
    UINT Id;
} DataC;

void GetDataC( int ArrSize, DataC** DArr );
```

**DataCollection.cpp**

```
#include "DataCollection.h"

void GetDataC( int ArrSize, DataC** DArr )
{

    int count = 0;
    int strSize = 10;
    *DArr = (DataC*)CoTaskMemAlloc( ArrSize * sizeof(DataC));
    DataC* CurData = *DArr;
    char TestS[] = "SomeText00";
    for ( int count = 0; count < ArrSize; count++,CurData++ )
    {
        TestS[strSize-1] = count + '0';
        CurData->Id = count;
        CurData->buffer = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*strSize);
        strcpy(CurData->buffer, TestS);
    }
}
```

**test the collection:**

```
int main(void)
{

    StpWatch Stw;long ResSw;

    DataC* TestDataArr;// maybe use DataC TestDataArr[] instead...

    GetDataC(100000, &TestDataArr);
}
```

how can i read the collection within a loop ?

for...

```
std::cout<<TestDataArr[count].buffer<<std::endl;
```

or ?

```
std::cout<<TestDataArr->buffer<<std::endl;
```

**What is the correct implementation to read each element in a loop?**

thanks for your time.

Comment: std::cout<<TestDataArr[count]->buffer<<std::endl;

Comment: @user2970916 then please review `GetDataC()`  cause that's the bipping version...wait checking . i put `.` instead of `->`

Comment: @user2970916 both ways that do compile..... bipping from the vs console pc bips.. you know them.. (ver 1) `for(int count=0; condition ; count++, collection++) with  cout::collection->member` - (ver 2) `for(int count=0; condition ; count++) with  cout::collection[count].member` the code is running slow and bips

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DataC* TestDataArr` and `DataC TestDataArr[]` are the same thing.  That said, when you try to reference TestDataArr you may do one of two things:

```
TestDataArr[index].buffer
```

or

```
(TestDataArr + index)->buffer
```

Because `TestDataArr` is a pointer you must deference it before you may use any of its members, this is what index does.  Using the first method, as an array index, the pointer is dereferenced at `index` in the array and you then may use `.` to access members of the object.  The second method, `index` advances the pointer to the memory location but does not dereference the pointer, so you must use `->` to then access its members.

So to print the buffer in a loop, you could use either:

```
std::cout << TestDataArr[count].buffer << std::endl;
```

or

```
std::cout << (TestDataArr + count)->buffer << std::endl;
```

The blipping you mention is probably  because of `TestS[strSize-1] = count + '0';` where `count + '0'` creates a character outside of the ASCII range.  Some of these characters will cause console beeps.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in `TestS[strSize-1] = count + '0';`. When you pass `ArrSize == 100 0000` then in the `for` loop the `count + '0'` value at a some moment exceeds the range of `char` and you get a char value in the range `[0-31]` (non-printable characters). At least use

```
TestS[strSize-1] = '0' + count % (126 - '0');
```

The last char of `TestS` will be changed in the range [48-126] (ASCII printable characters).

Comment: thanks for paying attention to the details, it's greate cause that was a test, comparing `char*` vs `BSTR` speed, though funny that i jump to conclusions : C# marshaling the array with `char*` is faster , also c++ **debug** BUT , finally release mode, BSTR wins.

Comment: nice trick with the modulus i wouldn't think of doing it with `char`

Comment: update. `BSTR` `wchar_t*` `char*`...  from slowest to fastest, [char*] is the fastest